# Get value of a Custom Attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div>
            <table id="dataTable">
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr id="row_1"></tr>
                    <tr id="row_2"></tr>
                    <tr id="row_3"></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>

</tr>
```

How can I get the value of a id in tr using jQuery? I have tried .attr but failed.

```
var row = jQuery('<tr>').attr("id", "row_" + item.autoID);
row.append(jQuery('<td>').append(jQuery('<input>').attr('type', 'checkbox', 'javascript:deleteChecked(' + item.autoID + ');').attr('id', 'check_id_')));


 <input type="button" value="Delete" id="delete_check" disabled onclick="deleteChecked()"/>
```

I'm trying to get the tr attribute 'row_' + id. I have a checkbox. If you select the checkbox and then hit delete. It should delete the row with the specific id or all the checked rows.

So far I have got:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#check_id_', function(id){
jQuery('#delete_check').attr("disabled",!jQuery('#check_id_').is(":checked"));
//var row = jQuery(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').attr('id');
// console.log(row); //doesn't work

});  

function deleteChecked(id){
//grab the checked row ids

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry what exactly are you trying to do? If you want just the `tr` element of the correct id how about just: `var row = jQuery("#row_" + item.autoID);`

Comment: To get an attribute use `$('<selector>').attr('attributeName')`. If you pass a second parameter, the attribute will be *set*. The second line is a complete mess, and I can't even figure out what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the rows with checked checkboxes in them and fetch their ID's, something like this should do the trick:

```
$('#dataTable')
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
    .closest('tr')
    .each(function(ind, ele){
        var id = $(ele).attr('id');
        //do something with the id here
    });
```

See [**this demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9u6fknhd/2/)

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: var rowID = jQuery('<tr>').attr("id"); returns undefined. In the delete function I need to check for the checked boxes, grab the row ids and make an ajax request to the servlet and remove the rows with the ids sent. But the issue is I'm trying to grab the ids, which is not working.

Comment: You really need to put all this into practice, e.g. in a JSFiddle, as it has several mistakes and misleading comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, I would suggest approaching this problem in a slightly different way.

- You simple *cannot* have duplicate IDs in your HTML. ID lookups use a fast lookup dictionary that can only store *one* element per id value so only the first is ever found.
- Avoid using *inline event handlers* (like `onclick=""`) at all costs in jQuery. It separates the handler registration from the handler response for no benefit and does not allow some of the additional cool event features jQuery provides (e.g. multiple handlers).
- Use *delegated event handler* for your delete operations. This simplifies the HTML and allows for dynamic elements/rows in a far simpler way.
- The way your question reads, it seems odd to use checkboxes instead of buttons for the delete. Use buttons instead unless you have good reason not to.
- The rows do not need ID's unless those IDs are used for some other purpose. Just delete the row `closest` to the delete button that is clicked.
- Use the `$('<htmltag>', {'prop': 'value', 'prop2', 'value2'})` syntax to create new elements with properties. It is shorter and easier to read.

So, putting all that together, you get the following to create a new row:

```
var row = $('<tr>', {
    "id": "row_" + item.autoID,
    text: "NEW ROW"
});
row.append($('<td>').append($('<input>', {
    'type': 'button',
    'value': 'X',
    'class': 'deleteme'
})));

$('#dataTable').append(row);
```

and this simple code to delete the row that has its `deleteme` 'X' button pressed:

```
$('#dataTable').on('click', '.deleteme', function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

This is a *delegated* event handler. It *delegates* responsibility for listening for the `click` event to a non-changing ancestor element. When a click event bubble up to that element, it *then* applies the jQuery selector (in this case the class `deleteme`) and then runs your callback function against any matching elements *that caused the event in the first place*. The upshot is that the `deleteme` buttons only need to exist at event time for this to work.

Clean and simple.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/k5rh82cz/

*Now if you actual aim is different, you need to explain how you want it to appear too* :)